# Algorithm to make a mutation waterfall plot (coded in R)

Tags: r, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have m genes of interest and n samples. I score a mutation of a gene as a 1 and non-mutation as zero, so that I have an m x n matrix. I want an algorithm that orders the data so that I can reproduce the matrix plot below. I'm coding this up in R, so code is welcome but not necessary.

Clearly I start by ordering the rows such that the row with the most mutations across all samples is top:

```
data.mutations <- data.mutations[order(rowSums(data.mutations), decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

I can't figure out how to sort the columns though. The first step is easy, I sort the columns by the first row:

```
data.mutations <- data.mutations[ , order(data.mutations[1, ], decreasing = TRUE)]
```

Now I get stuck tough. A naive approach would require a lot of loops. There must be a nicer solution.

[image: Mutation waterfall]

Comment: What order do you expect the columns to be in? You haven't explicitly stated the organizational rules except, other than to reproduce the single matrix plot shown - and a single example isn't enough to conclusively infer rule. I have a guess: all mutations columns w/ mutation in row 1 appear before columns w/o mutation in row 1; then repeat within each block for row 2, row 3, etc.

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. But yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column A should appear to the left of a column B if A[1] > B[1]. In case of a tie, compare A[2] to B[2], and so on and so forth. In other words, a comparison operator is defined on the columns by comparing their values in decreasing order of row number. This can be encoded in a single scalar value by assigning a value sum[r=1 to n] C[n]*2^(1-r). (In a language other than R, this could be done by creating an integer whose bits correspond to the values of the column). Then the columns should be sorted in decreasing value of this encoded scalar. In R,

```
n <- 15
m <- 20
p <- 0.15
mat <- matrix(0,n,m)
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {
    mat[i,j] = rbinom(1,1,0.15)
  }
}
print(mat)

# Order by row
mat <- mat[order(rowSums(mat),decreasing=TRUE),]

# Order by column
code <- function(column) {
  n <- length(column)
  pow <- 2^-(0:(n-1))
  return (column %*% pow)
}
mat <- mat[,order(apply(mat,2,code),decreasing=TRUE)]

print(mat)
```